ModelAndView inside another ModelAndView
The main page :ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/layout");
The panel page:ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/panel");
layout.jsp
<style>.....</style> 
<!-- Panel display  -->
<div class="container row" id="container"></div>
<script>.....</script> 

panel.jsp
<c:forEach var="panel" items='${panelData}'>
  <div class="panel-container col-lg-${panel.size}">
   ..samplecontent...
  </div>
</c:forEach>

i want to show the list of panel in the panel.jsp page but needs to be inside the layout.jsp so that as to get all the style and functionalities from the layout.jsp instead of the panel.jsp
The Problem is with the controller code ie. ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/layout"); is getting replaced with the mav the is return from the editPanel()
i want to load the "dashboard/layout" and inside it i want to display the "dashboard/panel" for some scripts to run
@RequestMapping("DashboardController/loadLayout")
    public ModelAndView loadLayout() {
    System.out.println("====Inside DashboardController#loadLayout====");
        //list of dashboards 
    List<Dashboard> dashboards = dashboardManagerService.findAllActive();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/layout");
    Set<Panel> panelData = new HashSet<>();
    for (Dashboard dashboard : dashboards) {
        //panelData from the dashboard
        panelData.addAll(dashboard.getLayoutPanels());
    }
    if (!panelData.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("inside the else part " + panelData);
        return editPanel(panelData);
    } else {
        System.out.println("inside the if part " + panelData);
    }

    return mav;
    }

    
    public ModelAndView editPanel(Set<Panel> panelData) {
    System.out.println("====Inside DashboardController#editPanel====");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/panel");
    mav.addObject("panelData", panelData);
    mav.setViewName("dashboard/panel");
    return mav;
    }


included the page in the layout page
<div class="container row" id="container">
    <%@ include file="panel.jsp"%>
</div>

and pass the value panelData to the mav
 @RequestMapping("DashboardController/loadLayout")
    public ModelAndView loadLayout() {
    System.out.println("====Inside DashboardController#loadLayout====");
    List<Dashboard> dashboards = dashboardManagerService.findAllActive();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("dashboard/layout");
    Set<Panel> panelData = new HashSet<>();
    for (Dashboard dashboard : dashboards) {
        panelData.addAll(dashboard.getLayoutPanels());
    }
    if (!panelData.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("inside the else part " + panelData);
        mav.addObject("panelData", panelData);
    }
    return mav;
    }

